# azuredevops docker build failing while coping the files after the build

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have below task in my build pipeline:

```
- bash: |
          echo "To test file exists and can be copied inside DOckerfile"
          cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/properties/config.properties
          ls -ltr $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/pipelines/
          cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/
          echo $(pwd)
          ls -ltr $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/
          echo "Started Building Docker Image"
          docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .
        displayName: 'Build Docker Image'
```

But it fails, while coping configCreate/properties/config.properties inside the dockefile.

Dockerfile

```
COPY properties/config.properties ${SDC_HOME}
```

Also I tried to pass the `workingDIR` as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate` during the Docker build command as argument and my Docker file would be then

```
COPY ${workingDIR}/configCreate/properties/config.properties ${SDC_HOME}
```

Everytime it fails stating `No such file or directory`
Is there something I should do so that files can be copied ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `workingDirctory` context like below in order to files to be copied properly inside Docker.

```
- bash: |
          cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/
          echo "Started Building Docker Image with tag $latestECRTag"
          docker build -t test:latest -f Dockerfile .


        displayName: 'Build Docker Image with Tag.'
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configCreate/
```

now inside Dockerfile copy is working fine.

```
COPY properties/config.properties ${SDC_HOME}
```

Missing this `workingDirectory` will cause no files or directory error.